# SQL Query for Counting Consecutive Reservations

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

so far I have made the following query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(check_in AS date) = CAST('$date' as date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_arrivals,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(check_out AS date) = CAST('$date' as date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_departures,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (CAST(check_in AS date) <= CAST('$date' as date) AND CAST(check_out AS date) > CAST('$date' as date)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_stayovers
FROM bookings_beds24
```

The above very simple query takes a `$date` and counts the `check_in`, `check_out` and stayovers of that date.

I am looking to create a query which will allow me to count/calculate the **switchovers**. Switchovers are two different bookings where one checks out and the other checks in on the same date.

Do you think something like that is possible using just an sql query? I am currently working on migrating the above three queries and in the meantime I am looking to be able to count the consecutive bookings.

Please bare in mind that the bookings_beds24 table holds the `check_in`, `check_out` dates and a `room_id` cause it stores data for multiple rooms.

Edit: Currently working on something like that but it obviously does not work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT check_in FROM bookings_beds24 WHERE room_id='208979') AS a, 
    (SELECT COUNT(book_id) AS total FROM bookings_beds24 WHERE check_out=a.check_in AND room_id='208979') AS b;
```

Comment: If a check_out happens, and a check_in happens on the same day for a different room, how do you know that it is a switchover and not just a separate booking?

Comment: What is the datatype of columns `check_in` and `check_out`?

Comment: Adding `create table` statements, sample data and desired results to your question would help us help you here.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by partially rephrasing your current query.

Assuming that:

- `check_in` and `check_out` are of a `datetime` or `timestamp` datatype (meaning that they store a date *and* a time)
- `$date` is a query parameter (`?`), that is given as a `date` (without a time portion)

We could:

- use a subquery so we don't need to repeat the parameter multiple times
- move part of the date filtering logic to the `on` clause of the `join`
- avoid casting the timestamps and filter with half-open intervals instead (this is more efficient)
- leverage the fact that MySQL evaluates predicates as `0` (false) and `1` (true) in numeric context to shorten the conditional `sum`s.

So:

```sql
select 
    sum(b.check_in  >= r.refdate)                  as total_arrivals,
    sum(b.check_out <  r.refdate + interval 1 day) as total_departures,
    sum(b.check_in < r.refdate and b.check_out >= r.refdate + interval 1 day) as total_stayovers
from (select ? refdate) r
inner join bookings_beds24 b 
    on b.check_in < r.refdate + interval 1 day and b.check_out >= r.refdate
```

I am suspicious about your definition of a stayover; your query counts all arrivals and departures of the day as stayovers, which does not seem right; mine only takes in account bookings that started *before* the reference date and ended on *a later day*.

---

When it comes to counting the switchovers: one option is to pre-aggregate by room, so we can then identify the arrivals/departures that happened on the same room:

```sql
select 
    sum(arrivals)                        as total_arrivals, 
    sum(departures)                      as total_departures, 
    sum(stayovers)                       as total_stayovers,
    sum(arrivals = 1 and departures = 1) as total_switchovers
from (
    select b.room_id,
        sum(b.check_in  >= r.refdate)                  as arrivals,
        sum(b.check_out <  r.refdate + interval 1 day) as departures,
        sum(b.check_in < r.refdate and b.check_out >= r.refdate + interval 1 day) as stayovers
    from (select ? refdate) r
    inner join bookings_beds24 b 
        on b.check_in < r.refdate + interval 1 day and b.check_out >= r.refdate
    group by b.room_id
) b
```

Note that with this logic a switchover always counts as both a departure and an arrival (on the other hand, of course not all departures or arrivals are switchovers).

---

Here is some sample data, that we'll use for reference date `'2023-04-07'`.

```
create table bookings_beds24 (
    room_id int,
    check_in datetime,
    check_out datetime
);
insert into bookings_beds24 values 
    (1, '2023-04-05 12:00:00', '2023-04-06 12:00:00'),  -- irrelevant
    (1, '2023-04-07 12:00:00', '2023-04-08 12:00:00'),  -- arrival
    (2, '2023-04-05 12:00:00', '2023-04-07 12:00:00'),  -- departure
    (3, '2023-04-05 12:00:00', '2023-04-08 12:00:00'),  -- stayover
    (4, '2023-04-06 12:00:00', '2023-04-07 12:00:00'),  -- switchover (departure)
    (4, '2023-04-07 12:00:00', '2023-04-10 12:00:00')   -- switchover (arrival)
;
```

Running the query for date `'2023-04-07'` yields:

| total_arrivals | total_departures | total_stayovers | total_switchovers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Here is **[a DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/auyAz5Hh)**.